# Define default index pattern from a yml file from ELK

Tags: elk

we are running ELK (8.7.0) over docker containers.

Whenever we are doing a restart to those containers (manually or due to some failure) the index pattern we defined in the kibana is getting reset and the next time we log in to the kibana we have to set it again

I'm trying to figure out if there is some configuration we can define in our kibana.yml \ elasticsearch.yml files that will automatically set the initial index pattern

when consulting chat gpt it suggested defining in the elasticsearch.yml:

```
# Elasticsearch Configuration
cluster.name: my_cluster
node.name: node-1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.type: single-node

# Custom Index Pattern
index_patterns:
  - name: all_indices
    pattern: "*-*"
```

and in the kibana.yml:

```
# Kibana Configuration
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]

# Custom Index Pattern
kibana.index: ".kibana"
kibana.defaultAppId: "discover"
kibana.indexPatterns: '["all_indices"]'
```

however, this leads to an error when trying to run the kibana container since it won't recognize the kibana.indexPatterns configuration.

so, is there any way to do so?